# How to override FOSUserBundle's ProfileController in Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to override some parts of the FOSUserBundle.

I have to custom the ProfileController (especially the showAction). I looked for a solution, and found that I had to create a new ProfileController in my UserBundle, and inherits the original FOSUserBundle ProfileController.

That's what I have done.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController as BaseController;

class ProfileController extends BaseController
```

I also know how to override twig views by creating same name files in my own UserBundle.

My problem is, that I don't know how to make Symfony using my ProfileController instead of the original.

Do I have to change routes in App/Config/routing.yml ?

Or simply create an .xml routing file in my UserBundle, and then import it in App/Config/routing.yml?

I first made the mistake of customing FOSUserBundle files but I know it wasn't the right way, that's why I'm trying to do clean changes now.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. You're extending `RegistrationController` as `ProfileController` - is that a mistake/typo?

Comment: True, I just copied the text from a wrong file, sorry, edited my message ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProfileController` is registered as a service named `fos_user.profile.controller` as you can see in [this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/profile.xml) configuration file.

In order to override the controller/service (for Symfony 3.4) you need to re-define this service inside your `app/config/services.yml`:

```
services:
  # [..]
  'fos_user.profile.controller':
    class: 'Your\Namespace\ProfileController'
    public: true
    arguments:
      - '@event_dispatcher'
      - '@fos_user.profile.form.factory'
      - '@fos_user.user_manager'
    calls:
      - [ 'setContainer', [ '@service_container' ]]
```

Now clear your cache. 
Symfony will then use your ProfileController class as the service named `fos_user.profile.controller`.